# not produce empty list of lists in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

**Background**

1) I have the following code to create a `df`

```
import pandas as pd
word_list = ['crayons', 'cars', 'camels']
l = ['there are many different crayons in the bright blue box',
     'i like a lot of sports cars because they go really fast',
     'the middle east has many camels to ride and have fun']
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Text'])
df

    Text
0   there are many different crayons in the bright blue box
1   i like a lot of sports cars because they go really fast
2   the middle east has many camels to ride and have fun
```

2) And I have the following code to create a function

```
 def find_next_words(row, word_list):

    sentence = row[0]

    # trigger words are the elements in the word_list
    trigger_words = []
    next_words = []
    last_words = []

    for keyword in word_list:

        words = sentence.split()
        for index in range(0, len(words) - 1):

            if words[index] == keyword:

                trigger_words.append(keyword)

                #get the 3 words that follow trigger word
                next_words.append(words[index + 1:index + 4]) 

                #get the 3 words that come before trigger word
                #DOES NOT WORK...PRODUCES EMPTY LIST
                last_words.append(words[index - 1:index - 4])


    return pd.Series([trigger_words, last_words, next_words], index = ['TriggerWords','LastWords', 'NextWords'])
```

3) This function uses the words in the `word_list` from above to find the 3 words that come **before** and **after** the `"trigger_words"` in the `word_list`

4) I then use the following code

```
df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: find_next_words(x, word_list), axis=1))
```

5) And it produce the following `df` which is close to what I want

```
Text                                  TriggerWords LastWords NextWords
0   there are many different crayons    [crayons]   [[]]    [[in, the, bright]]
1   i like a lot of sports cars          [cars]     [[]]    [[because, they, go]]
2   the middle east has many camels     [camels]    [[]]    [[to, ride, and]]
```

**Problem**

6) However, the `LastWords` column is an empty list of list `[[]]` . I think the problem is this line of code `last_words.append(words[index - 1:index - 4])` taken from the `find_next_words` function from above.

7) This is a bit confusing to me because the the `NextWords` column uses very similar code `next_words.append(words[index + 1:index + 4])` taken from the `find_next_words` function and it works.

**Question**

8) How do I fix my code so it does not produce the empty list of lists `[[]]` and instead it gives me the 3 words that come before the words in the `word_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `words[max(index - 4, 0):max(index - 1, 0)]` in the code.